# Creating Lead Forms Context card using Facebook API

Tags: php

There is an option for creating context card using ads sdk.But How can i upload the context card cover photo using this sdk.When i pass image url or files array it shows unknown error.Please look into the context card create section in this(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/create).Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I came across this same issue. Through some trial and error, I was able to find that you need to upload the image you wish to use for the cover photo to the page using [this api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads#single) and then hand the `ID` you get from that call as the `context_card.cover_photo_id` field.

Hope this helps!